# FTP files default download path(python)

Tags: python, ftp

when i download a file from ftp in python using retrbinary where are the files downloaded by default.Is there a way to change this default folder?
thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

The retrbinary function in the `ftplib` library takes a callback function that is called once for each block of data retrieved. You write this callback function yourself, and can therefore change the folder files are saved to.

Some example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from ftplib import FTP



ftphost, file_to_retrieve, output_path = sys.argv[1:4]

print "Retreiving %(file_to_retrieve)s from FTP host %(ftphost)s, saving to %(output_path)s" % locals()

ftp = FTP(ftphost)
ftp.login()

outfile = None
def data_callback(data):
    global outfile
    if outfile is None:
        outfile = open(output_path, 'w')

    outfile.write(data)

ftp.retrbinary("RETR %s" % file_to_retrieve, data_callback)

if outfile is not None:
    outfile.close()
```

To retreive `ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/kernel.org/linux/docs/man-pages/man-pages-3.32.tar.gz` and save it as `/tmp/man-pages.tar.gz`, run this code as follows:

```
$ python testftp.py ftp.sunet.se /pub/Linux/kernel.org/linux/docs/man-pages/man-pages-3.32.tar.gz /tmp/man-pages.tar.gz
```